# i want to extract the href having same classname in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

```html
<li></li>
<li></li>.
<li><span class-"mreinfp comp-text"><a class="">mail</a></span><li>
<li><span class-"mreinfp comp-text"><a href=""></a></span><li>
```

[here I have posted the sample code, I want to extract the href from mreinfp comp-text but email feilds also having the same class name,i have to try xpath but xpaths are varied depend upon the li , so I want extract the href value from mreinfp comp-text
(listed in last li)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPkCF.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPkCF.png)

Comment: Don't put screenshots..paste the code snippet instead

Comment: why image snapshot. ohh  !! new user.. delete this post or edit with the actual code. please refer how to put questions on stackoverflow ...

Comment: Please clear the requirement and paste complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
String hrefValue = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li/span[@class='mreinfp comp-text']/a[@href]")).getAttribute("href");
```

You will have the `href` value in `hrefValue`

Comment: I have to tried the above code,it shows the unable to find the element with specified path.its will take href  value for specified webpages.i have found the problem here li counts are varied so its shows the error for some pages